# How to pass dynamic variable in helm file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helmfile, helm3

I tried to pass value to helmfile with --set

```
 helmfile --file ./myfile.yaml sync --set tag=${TAG}

myfile.yaml
---

releases:
  - name: controll
    namespace: ns
    chart: {{ .Values.chart.path }}
    version: {{ .Values.version | default "" }}
    values:
      - image:
          repository: controller-repo
          tag: {{ .Values.agcm_tag }}
          pullPolicy: Never
      - values/anotherYaml.yaml
```

I got an error

```
in myfile.yaml: error during myfile.part.1 parsing: template: stringTemplate:14:25: executing "stringTemplate" at <.Values.tag>: map has no entry for key "tag"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the replacement here starts at the `.Values` root level.

What you want to replace here may be the value of `agcm_tag`

So you can try the following wording here:

```yaml
helmfile --file ./myfile.yaml sync --set agcm_tag=${TAG}
```

> [helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/)

Comment: I still get the same error, as if the `--set` value is not yet accessible in the helmfile, but accessible later in the deployment file.